# js : how to convert time to date (using moment)

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs

I have `moment(value).format("HH:mm")` which is converting

> 2022-08-09T12:10:50.001Z

to

> 18:30

but I want to do it in opposite way.

Like I receive `18:30:00` from the database and I want this format `2022-08-09T12:10:50.001Z`

Any solutions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this?

```
const time = moment('18:30:00', 'H:m:s');

console.log(time.toDate()); // Tue Aug 09 2022 18:30:00 GMT+0200
console.log(time.format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSS[Z]")) // 2022-08-09T18:30:00.000Z
```